# Multiple Shaders-Single Program or If-else conditions via a uniform variable?

Tags: opengl-es, shader

I want to ask a simple question about OpenGL ES 2.x (or I think it is valid for most of the recent OpenGL releases).

Which one of the following is faster? :

1. Attaching/Detaching multiple shaders depending on what I draw,
2. Having a uniform variable for checking the rendering mode; as a result of that I am going to have a bunch of if-else conditions(or i.e. a switch-case block). I know this is no good for GPU cores; however you may assume that i render same group of primitives subsequently; i.e. I do not switch from one mode to another so frequently.

If you may explain pros/cons of each solution; it would really be appreciated. A third solution is always welcome.

Comment: The answer may be different depending on if you're talking about desktop GL or GL ES. So which is it?

Comment: i am talking about OpenGL ES 2.0 and later releases for embedded systems.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on the volume of data to compute, whenever you are fragment processing bound and many more things.

As a rule of thumb, changing states should be avoided when possible as they trigger a pipeline flush. To make thinks worse, changing an uniform may also trigger a pipeline flush. If you are not using all your shaders throughput try with that conditional.

EDIT: If you reorder your data so that there are just an small amount of state changes it should be ok to change the shader and allow to output more fragments. But again, really depends on where is your bottleneck.

TIP: Measure.

Comment: In general, though, for mobile devices I've found that conditionals within a fragment shader are far slower in almost all cases than rendering groups of objects using different shaders. The simple presence of a conditional, even if it's not switched between states, can lead to a 10-20X reduction in rendering speed with mobile GPUs.

Comment: Yeah I think I didn't state my point clear enough, in case you have that conditional means you need to change the value of the uniform, which may trigger a recompilation and will lead to even lower numbers. I completely I agree with you. I would go first to change shader than adding the conditional.

Comment: himm.. Well i thought so.Since gpu cores are very bad for conditional statements; it would be better if i go for seperate shaders and sort out my data as well in order to gain max speed. Thx guys!

Comment: Post your performance findings here once you try this and mark it answered so that this questions is closed. Cheer!